# Custom validation not firing

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

FluentValidation version 8.5
ASP.NET version .NET Core 2.2

Summary
The validation is not firing, have I missed something?

// Usage

```
public class Validator : AbstractValidator<Command>
{
    public Validator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.File).SetValidator(new UploadValidator());
    }
}
```

// This is my custom validator.

```
public class UploadValidator : AbstractValidator<IFormFile>
{
    public UploadValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(m => m).NotNull()
            .WithMessage("File to upload is missing");
        
        RuleFor(m => m.Length).GreaterThan(0)
            .WithMessage("File size is too small");

        // 157286400 = 150mb;
        RuleFor(x => x.Length).NotNull().LessThanOrEqualTo(157286400)
            .WithMessage("File size is larger than allowed (150 Mb)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that integrates the MVC framework with FluentValidation? Also, if you don't have code explicitly integrating FluentValidation with the MVC framework, then your validators will not get triggered.

Comment: Everything is registered properly Startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

The `UploadValidator` class inherits from `AbstractValidator<IFormFile>`. By naming conventions, `IFormFile` is an interface. It looks like FluentValidation does not support validating interfaces, only concrete classes.

> To define a set of validation rules for a particular object, you will need to create a class that inherits from `AbstractValidator<T>`, where `T` is the ***type of class*** that you wish to validate.

Source: [Creating your first validator](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/start.html).

Since you have not posted the code for your view models, I cannot recommend a specific fix. On a more general note, if you have multiple kinds of file uploads, use a hierarchy of concrete classes if possible to validate the objects. You can still use the interface to process them, but it appears that FluentValidation needs classes.